# Post request different on production server

Tags: python-3.x, flask, production-environment

I have a Flask app that is working fine on my local computer. But on the production server it seems I have not configured something correctly.

This is my `ajax` function:

```
$('#btnSearch').on('click', function() {
  var query = $("#query").val()
  $('#loading-indicator').show();//Load button clicked show spinner
  $.ajax({
    url: '/',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {'query': query},
    success: function(response) {
        channels.clear();
        console.log("response", response);
   //....
```

This is `python` relevant code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  # app.run(debug=True)
  from waitress import serve
  serve(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=80)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def search():

if request.method == 'POST':
    # Get the search query from the form
    query = request.form['query']

    # Execute the MariaDB SELECT statement to get the matching rows
    channels = sql_maria.query(f"CALL `search_channels`('" + query + "')")
else:
    channels = sql_maria.query(f"SELECT Channel_Id, Channel_Name FROM Channel LIMIT 0")

return channels
```

Locally the `response` is an array, as it should be. But on production I get

```
response:  <html><head><META HTTP-EQUIV="Cache-control" CONTENT="no-cache"><META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="0;URL=/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi"></head><body></body></html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the code is fine, but I had to register the domain.